# Coupling of r.v.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

I am trying to answer this question.

> If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{B})$, show 
>   \begin{align*}
> \sup_{A \in \mathcal{B}} |P[X \in A] -P[Y \in A]| \le P[X \neq Y].
> \end{align*}

Things I tried.

\begin{align*}
|P[X \in A] -P[Y \in A]|&=P \{[X \in A] \Delta [Y \in A] \}\\
&=P\{ \omega: \left(X^{-1}(A)\backslash Y^{-1}(A)\right) \cup \left(Y^{-1}(A) \backslash X^{-1}(A) \right) \}\\
&=P\{ \omega: X^{-1}(A)\backslash Y^{-1}(A) \} + P \{Y^{-1}(A) \backslash X^{-1}(A) \}
\end{align*}
On the other hand 
\begin{align*}
 P[X \neq Y]&=P \{\omega: X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \Delta Y^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \}\\
&=P \{\omega: \left( X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \backslash Y^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))\right) \cup \left( Y^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \backslash X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))\right)   \}\\
&=P \left\{\omega: \left( X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \backslash Y^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))\right) \right\} + P \left\{ \left( Y^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})) \backslash X^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))\right)   \right\}
\end{align*}

Assuming all I did is correct. Next, I think, I must use definition of $\sup$ to show the rest. I feel like I am almost there. Can any one help? Thanks.

Comment: What is meant by e.g. $\{\omega: X^{-1}(A)\}$ or $\{\omega: X^{-1}(\mathcal B(\mathbb R))\}$? These notations are not okay.

Comment: By $\{\omega: X^{-1}(\mathcal{B(R)})\}=\{\omega: X^{-1}(A), A \in \mathcal{B(R)}\}$

Comment: Notations like $\{\omega: P(\omega)\}$ (where $P(\omega)$ means that $\omega$ has some property) make sense, but after the $:$ sign I cannot find any $\omega$. What is the property of $\omega$ here?

Comment: My friend. Sorry, for bad notation. This comes from my inexperience. The answer you provided is actually what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Very welcome and good luck with your study and experience-building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if $P$ is a probability and $R,S$ are measurable sets:

$\left|P\left(R\right)-P\left(S\right)\right|=\left|P\left(R\cap S^{c}\right)-P\left(R^{c}\cap S\right)\right|\leq P\left(R\cap S^{c}\right)+P\left(R^{c}\cap S\right)=P\left(R\triangle S\right)$

Applying that here gives for every $A\in\mathcal B$:

$\left|P\left\{ X\in A\right\} -P\left\{ Y\in A\right\} \right|\leq P\left(\left\{ X\in A\right\} \triangle\left\{ Y\in A\right\} \right)\leq P\left\{ X\neq Y\right\} $

The second inequality as a consequence of $\left\{ X\in A\right\} \triangle\left\{ Y\in A\right\} \subseteq\left\{ X\neq Y\right\} $

Comment: dear @drhab could you explain why $\{ X \in A\} \triangle \{Y \in A\} \subset \{X \neq Y \}$?

Comment: Suppose that $\omega\in\left\{ X\in A\right\} \triangle\left\{ Y\in A\right\} $. Then $\omega\in\left\{ X\in A\right\} \wedge\omega\notin\left\{ Y\in A\right\} $ or $\omega\notin\left\{ X\in A\right\} \wedge\omega\in\left\{ Y\in A\right\} $. That is: $X\left(\omega\right)\in A\wedge Y\left(\omega\right)\notin A$ or $X\left(\omega\right)\notin A\wedge Y\left(\omega\right)\in A$. Both possibilities imply that $X\left(\omega\right)\neq Y\left(\omega\right)$, i.e. $\omega\in\left\{ X\neq Y\right\} $.